ConTeXt equivalent for \textcommabelow (e.g. a t-comma)
In LaTeX, writing a t-comma (not to be confused with a t-cedilla) can be written using \textcommabelow{t}. What is the correct way for entering a t-comma using ConTeXt? Unfortunately, the official manual only shows how to enter a cedilla (see page 82).
Thanks in advance for your help!
P.S. Using the t-comma with Unicode works, but I prefer using ASCII. It is only required at a single place in my document, so a one-time solution would be great!

Try \Tcommaaccent and \tcommaaccent.


ConTeXt has a \withcommabelow command for this but at the moment it places a cedilla under the character like \withcedilla.

Thank you very much, it works perfectly!

@WolfgangSchuster : I can talk to Hans about it. guemax: Glad it worked.
